# How to run PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser on Windows with WAMP?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, wamp

I am currently running **Windows 7** with **WAMP** installed.

I am trying to install the **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to run the below code.

I am getting a fatal error message. This is likely because the DOM Parser is not installed or in the right place.

**How do I install the Parser? Do I simply copy it into a WAMP folder or do I call it from a php file?**

Error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in     
 C:\wamp\www\PHP_SCRAPER\_jobs\jobs_dom.php on line 4

<?php
```

Code:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';

?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php

// Include the php dom parser    
include_once 'path_to_php_dom_parser.php';

// Create DOM from URL or file

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';

?>
```

You need to include the parser script from the location you stored it in on the server